# REPLACE SOME STRING VALUE DYNAMICALLY IN SQL

Tags: sql

i have a table like this

```
id     name                        parentid
1     LOTTEMART                    1.3
2     LOTTEMART Jabodetabek        1.3.10
3     LOTTEMART HPM GANDARIA CITY  1.3.10.1
4     LOTTEMART HPM RATU PLAZA     1.3.10.1
5     LOTTEMART HPM KELAPA GADING  1.3.10.1
```

i want when i update LOTTEMART 1.3 be 1.4 then the siblings and child automatically update like this

```
 id     name                         parentid
  1     LOTTEMART                    1.4
  2     LOTTEMART Jabodetabek        1.4.10
  3     LOTTEMART HPM GANDARIA CITY  1.4.10.1
  4     LOTTEMART HPM RATU PLAZA     1.4.10.1
  5     LOTTEMART HPM KELAPA GADING  1.4.10.1
```

or if i want to update LOTTEMART Jabodetabek  1.4.10 be 1.4.18 i want the result like this

```
 id     name                        parentid
 1     LOTTEMART                    1.4
 2     LOTTEMART Jabodetabek        1.4.18
 3     LOTTEMART HPM GANDARIA CITY  1.4.18.1
 4     LOTTEMART HPM RATU PLAZA     1.4.18.1
 5     LOTTEMART HPM KELAPA GADING  1.4.18.1
```

i try to use concat / replace but not showing what what i want..
any other suggestions ?

Comment: Mind sharing what you've tried? That would be sooo in the spirit of this site...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try this Query for Your Answer :

For First Output :

```
 UPDATE TestTable123412
 SET parentid = replace(parentId,'1.3','1.4')
 WHERE name='LOTTEMART' or Id >= (select id from TestTable123412 
 where name='LOTTEMART')
```

For Second Output :

```
 UPDATE TestTable123412
 SET parentid = replace(parentId,'1.4.10','1.4.18')
 WHERE name='LOTTEMART Jabodetabek' or Id >= (select id from TestTable123412 
 where name='LOTTEMART Jabodetabek')
```